# Is it possible to to execute code befor all tests are run?

Tags: .net, mbunit

I am writing integration tests.Now, before tests are run I want to setup the database with initial data.For this, I have created a separate project, which is run before test project is executed(using MSBuild file).But, I want to merge the db setup code in testproject, and have it executed before any tests get executed.I am using MBunit 3.Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a class with the [[AssemblyFixture]](http://www.gallio.org/api/html/T_MbUnit_Framework_AssemblyFixtureAttribute.htm) attribute; and a few methods into that class with the [[FixtureSetUp]](http://www.gallio.org/api/html/T_MbUnit_Framework_FixtureSetUpAttribute.htm) and [[FixtureTearDown]](http://www.gallio.org/api/html/T_MbUnit_Framework_FixtureTearDownAttribute.htm) attributes to define assembly-level setup and teardown methods.

```
[AssemblyFixture]
public class MyAssemblyFixture
{
   [FixtureSetUp]
   public void SetUp()
   {
      // Code to be run before any test fixture within the assembly are executed.
   }

   [FixtureTearDown]
   public void TearDown()
   {
      // Code to be run after all test fixture within the assembly are executed.
   }
}
```

In fact, the syntax is similar to what is usually done at test fixture level with the well-known [[TestFixture]](http://www.gallio.org/api/html/T_MbUnit_Framework_TestFixtureAttribute.htm), [[SetUp]](http://www.gallio.org/api/html/T_MbUnit_Framework_SetUpAttribute.htm), and [[TearDown]](http://www.gallio.org/api/html/T_MbUnit_Framework_TearDownAttribute.htm) attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Generally test frameworks have method attributes to allow code to be executed before each test and after each test and before a test run and after a test run.  I don't know the attributes for mbunit as I haven't used it.

Check out this link...  I am sure mbunit would have attributes that are similar to nunit

http://blogs.msdn.com/nnaderi/archive/2007/02/01/mstest-vs-nunit-frameworks.aspx

Comment: what i want is that - before any tests are executed, my db setup code must run once(not before every test)

Comment: According to Google, MBunit supports [TestFixtureSetUp] attribute which marks method to be executed before every test in fixture.

Answer (score 0):

MBunit doesn't have excessive documentation, but quick googling gives [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/gunit.aspx) from which I can tell that MBUnit has similar attributes to NUnit [SetUp] and [TearDown]. Methods decorated with those are executed before, and after each test respectively.

Comment: Well, there is pretty complete documentation of the entire API here: http://www.gallio.org/api/index.aspx

Comment: You are right, the Gallio Book Project is still in a very early stage. But again, the API documentation is very complete and contains a lot of useful samples.